# ParseUI Android is not working

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I have a problem with ParseUI Android. I was using parse 1.9.0 and FacebookUtils 1.9.0 because I needed only Facebook login. But now I need usual login, with username and password as well as Facebook login. I followed the guide, imported ParseLoginUI as a module. But then I got problems with running the project. I solved them, deleted old libraries added new ones. Now the project is running, but Login with facebook is not working. When I press the button it just shows loading progress bar and then nothing. I'm testing it on Sony xperia, API 21. I think I made something wrong when I deleted libraries and was adding another ones. I also changed the gradle files a little, thought it would help. But it didn't.

Comment: How do we help? You need to give details of any errors. There's nothing to go on here.

Comment: There is no errors at all. I understand that it's almost impossible to solve this. Just hoped that someone faced such problem.